# How to update multiple fields?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting a number of errors, related to profile_address not being defined. Most of this current code came from a working update for 1 value, I've since tried to add in updating a second value and I would like to expand it to update another 10 values.

I think the issue is the variables are not being parsed correctly in my application.

I initially tried to add it to an array as seen in the model however this hasn't worked.

I think this is a fairly trivial problem and I'm sure it's a simple solution that I haven't thought of yet.

View:

```
<form action="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>login/editUserProfile_action" method="post">
    <label for="comment">Name</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="profile_name"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label for="comment">Address</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="profile_address"></textarea>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    public function editUserProfile()
{
    Auth::checkAuthentication();
    $this->View->render('login/editUserProfile');
}

/**
 * Edit user profile (perform the real action after form has been submitted)
 * Auth::checkAuthentication() makes sure that only logged in users can use this action and see this page
 */
// make this POST
public function editUserProfile_action()
{
    Auth::checkAuthentication();
    UserModel::editUserProfile(Request::post('profile_name', 'profile_address'));
    Redirect::to('login/editUserProfile');
}
```

Model:

```
    public static function editUserProfile($profile_name, $profile_address)
{

    // write to database, if successful ...
    if (UserModel::saveUserProfile(Session::get('user_id'), $profile_name, $profile_address)) {
        Session::set(array('profile_name', $profile_name, 'profile_address', $profile_address));
        Session::add('feedback_positive', Text::get('FEEDBACK_EMAIL_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL'));
        return true;
    }
    Session::add('feedback_negative', Text::get('FEEDBACK_UNKNOWN_ERROR'));
    return false;
}   
/**
 * Writes new data to database
 *
 * @param $user_id int user id
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public static function saveUserProfile($user_id, $profile_name, $profile_address)
{
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $query = $database->prepare("UPDATE users SET profile_name = :profile_name, profile_address = :profile_address WHERE user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute(array(':profile_name' => $profile_name, ':profile_address' => $profile_address, ':user_id' => $user_id));
    $count =  $query->rowCount();
    if ($count == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show where you have been stuck.?

Comment: @NarendraSisodia An example of the error I am receiving is: Undefined variable: profile_address in C:\wamp\www\application\model\UserModel.php on line 358

Comment: Please stop using procedural programming paradigm and learn basics of OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the arrays, I have fixed the issue by doing the following:

```
public function editUserProfile_action()
{
Auth::checkAuthentication();
UserModel::editUserProfile(Request::post('profile_name'),
Request::post('profile_address'));
Redirect::to('login/editUserProfile');
}
```

This was fixed by doing the same thing in the model.